# Displaying field from another screen

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have created one custom field each in **Sales Orders** screen and in **Add SO Line dialog box in Invoices** screen to display the value of **Tariff Code in Stock Items** screen. I managed to display them using the code below:

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
{
    #region UsrTariffCode
    [PXDBString(30)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tariff Code", Enabled = false)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOLine.inventoryID,InventoryItem.hSTariffCode>))]
    public virtual string UsrTariffCode { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTariffCode : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrTariffCode> { }
    #endregion
}
    public class SOLineForDirectInvoiceExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.DAC.Projections.SOLineForDirectInvoice>
{
    #region UsrTariffCode
    [PXDBString(50, BqlField = typeof(SOLineExt.usrTariffCode))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tariff Code", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual string UsrTariffCode { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTariffCode : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrTariffCode> { }
    #endregion
}
```

Is there an alternative way of doing this via **FieldUpdated** or **FieldDefaulting** method?

I have tried inserting the code below in **SOLineExt** class but failed to get the desired result.

```
    protected void _(Events.FieldUpdated<SOLine, SOLine.inventoryID> e)
    {
        SOLine row = e.Row;
        if (row.InventoryID != null)
        {
            InventoryItem item = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOLine.inventoryID>(e.Cache, row) as InventoryItem;
            e.Cache.SetValueExt<SOLineExt.usrTariffCode>(row, item.HSTariffCode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FeildSelecting event as an alternative to programmatically getting and setting the value you need.

```
 void ARDocumentResult_YourFeild_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

        var returnValue = PerformLogicToGetValue();
        e.ReturnValue = returnValue;
    }

    private string PerformLogicToGetValue()
    {
       //do processing to get what you need...
       return "your desired value";
    }
```